Unable to dockerize a Node.js / SvelteKit app
I have a small empty SvelteKit template project which runs well locally but when I try Dockerizing it fails.
Can anyone help me understand why isn't the build found?
This is the Dockerfile:
FROM node:lts-slim AS deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./
RUN npx pnpm i --frozen-lockfile

FROM node:lts-slim AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN npx pnpm run build

FROM node:lts-slim AS runner
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN useradd -u 1001 -s /usr/sbin/nologin -m -d /home/sveltekit sveltekit
RUN groupadd nodejs && usermod -aG nodejs sveltekit
COPY --from=builder --chown=sveltekit:nodejs /app/build ./build
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

USER sveltekit
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "./build"]

the is the package.json file:
{
    "name": "sveltekit-docker",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "lint": "prettier --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --write ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^3.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/eslint": "^8.56.0",
        "eslint": "^8.56.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.35.1",
        "prettier": "^3.1.1",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^3.1.2",
        "svelte": "^4.2.7",
        "vite": "^5.0.3"
    },
    "type": "module"
}

and this is the (partially redacted eliminating first steps with no error) error trace:
bob ~/code/sveltekit_docker [main] $ docker build -t sd --no-cache .
[+] Building 8.9s (15/17)                                  docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
... lines without errors omitted....
 => [deps 4/4] RUN npx pnpm i --frozen-lockfile                            4.1s
 => [builder 4/5] COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules        0.3s
 => [builder 5/5] RUN npx pnpm run build                                   3.1s
 => ERROR [runner 5/7] COPY --from=builder --chown=sveltekit:nodejs /app/  0.0s
------
[runner 5/7] COPY --from=builder --chown=sveltekit:nodejs /app/build ./build:
------
Dockerfile:18
--------------------
  16 |     RUN useradd -u 1001 -s /usr/sbin/nologin -m -d /home/sveltekit sveltekit
  17 |     RUN groupadd nodejs && usermod -aG nodejs sveltekit
  18 | >>> COPY --from=builder --chown=sveltekit:nodejs /app/build ./build
  19 |     COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
  20 |     COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 7b0a430b-35d6-4fc8-a6dd-db95ac242422::eeh419kyu0c4wj7k9gabjqe4w: "/app/build": not found


Don't know if it's the reason, but you're copying the node_modules folder on your host to the container. You should not do that (some npm packages have different implementations for different OS), but you should run npm install as an instruction in the Dockerfile.

Hi and thanks for helping. But I am copying the modules installes by the deps stage and therefore specific to the platform on which I am building. Is that wrong?

Sorry, don't mind me. My comment was based on that I didn't find install anywhere, but I now see you use i instead.

I have a SvelteKit typescript project managed with pnpm
This project needs to use two REST APIs, one GET /availablemodels to fetch the names of embedding models to populate a dropdown and one POST to /hybridsearch with four parameters needed in the body (search string, model name, alpha value, number of items to return) to trigger an hybrid search to the Weaviate backend database.
The following is a good layered cacheable Dockerfile:
# Stage 1: Node with pnpm
FROM node:lts-bullseye-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install -g pnpm

# Stage 2: Build Stage, install prerequisites
FROM base AS build
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./
RUN pnpm install
COPY . .
RUN pnpm run build

# Stage 3: Production Stage
FROM base AS production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build --chown=node:node /app/build ./build
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./
RUN pnpm install --prod
#  Runtime environment
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV MODELS_HOST=localhost
USER node
EXPOSE 3000

Stage 1 is only to build a base image with the long term support slim version of the Node docker image (only marginally larger than the apline version but the latter sometimes gives me problems) an also install pnpm, the faster better npm alternative-
Stage 2 installs all prerequisite modules, copies the whole project (minus .dockerignore) and runs a build which will resut in the project built in /app/build
Stage 3 will copy the build onto the original base image, installs only the production prerequisites, sets a few runtime variables.
The Dockerfile only describes the recipe to build the container. The actual run instructions are responsability of the docker-compose.yml files of which I’ll copy only some relevant parts:
services:
  weaviate:
    image: cr.weaviate.io/semitechnologies/weaviate:1.24.11
    command:
      - "--host=0.0.0.0"
      - "--port=8080"
      - "--scheme=http"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50051:50051"
    volumes:
      - weaviate_data:/var/lib/weaviate
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: info 
      ENABLE_CUDA: 0
      LIMIT_RESOURCES: true
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 25
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: true
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: /var/lib/weaviate
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: finland
      #ENABLE_MODULES: text2vec-cohere 
      #DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: text2vec-transformers
      #DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: text2vec-cohere
      #COHERE_APIKEY: N4K8WCmFYNLCR6YsGE5UvGinXko0KBH7nmOowfWB
      #TRANSFORMERS_INFERENCE_API: http://t2v-e5-mistral:8080
      DISABLE_TELEMETRY: true
      GOMAXPROCS: 4
    networks:
      - weaviate_net
  llm_fast:
    build:
      context: /home/mema/code/llm_fast
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: llm_fast:v0.6
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: "/app/app"
      HF_HUB_CACHE: "/home/llmuser/.cache/huggingface/hub"
    command: gunicorn -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8086 --timeout 300 app.vectorize:app
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    volumes:
      - llm_cache:/home/llmuser/.cache
    user: "1000:1000"
    networks:
      - weaviate_net

  aisearch:
    build:
      context: /home/mema/code/aisearch
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: aisearch:v0.1
    command: gunicorn -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8088 --timeout 30 search:app
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    user: "1000:1000"
    networks:
      - weaviate_net
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - llm_fast
      - weaviate

  frontvect:
    build:
      context: /home/mema/code/skwhfe
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: skwhfe:v0.1
    command: node /app/build/index.js
    ports:
      - "5555:3000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    networks:
      - weaviate_net
      - mema_network
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - llm_fast
      - aisearch
networks:
  weaviate_net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  weaviate_data:
    name: weaviate_mema
  llm_cache:
mema@newisa:~/mema_docker_compose$ 

The frontvect service will be built and run by docker compose according to the Dockerfile in the code’s directory and will run the command “node /app/build/index.js” which will launch the application as built by the Dockerfile under Node. Node will expose its port 3000 in the container and this is mapped onto the host’s 5555 port, so the browser will be pointed there.
Also note that within a docker compose project the other containers running the backend services are reachable by an hostname that is equal to the service name. So within the frontvect container you will fetch the names of the models with a GET to http://llm_fast:8086 and the results with a POST to http://aisearch:8088. Within the container localhost refers only to the ports within the container itself.
Please note that to work the SK project must use the node adapter.
